# Fastest way to find the best level of compression of an image

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I wrote a function (in Python) that saves an image with a certain quality level (0 to 100, higher is better). Depending on the quality level, the final file is bigger or smaller (in byte).

I need to write a function that selects the best possible quality level for an image, keeping it under a **maximum file size** (in byte). The only way I can do it is by attempts.

The simplest approach is: save the file with a certain quality and if it is bigger than expected then reduce the quality and so forth.
Unfortunately this approach is very time consuming. Even if I reduce the quality by five points at each iteration, the risk is that I have to save the same file 21 times before I find the right quality.

Another solution is: try with the half of the previous quality and focus on the lower range or on the higher range of quality according to the result.
Let me clarify:

1. assuming that quality can be between 0 and 100, try with quality = 50
2. if file size is higher than expected, focus on the lower quality range (e.g. 0-49) otherwise on the higher one (e.g. 51-100).
3. set the quality value in the middle of the considered range and save the file (e.g. 25 if lower range and 75 if higher range); return to 2
4. exit when the range is smaller than 5

This second solution requires always 6 iterations.

Here it is a Python implementation:

```
limit_file_size = 512 # maximum file size, change this for different results

q_max = 100
q_min = 0
quality = q_min + (q_max - q_min) // 2

while True:
    file_size = save_file(quality)

    if (q_max - q_min) <= 5: break

    if file_size > limit_file_size:
        q_max = quality
    else:
        q_min = quality

    quality = q_min + (q_max - q_min) // 2
```

Please note that function *save_file* is not provided for brevity, a fake implementation of it can be the following:

```
import math
def save_file(quality):
    return int(math.sqrt(quality))*100
```

How to reduce the amount of cycles required by the above function to converge to a valid solution?

Comment: "Any idea to improve this solution or for a better approach ?" This is not an answerable, on-topic question here - this is *not a discussion forum* and we don't deal in questions that are this open-ended or subjective.

Comment: I rephrased the final question to be more specific

Comment: Ideas: Use [interpolation/"computed" search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search). "Find" a map between *JPEG image quality percentages* and encoding size and modify your search accordingly. `How to reduce the amount of cycles required` relax your requirement for *best quality not exceeding size limit*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a binary search function like you mentioned and save the result in a dictionary so that next iteration it will check if the file size quality was calculated already like that:

```
# { file_size : quality }
{ 512 : 100 , 256 : 100, 1024 : 27 }
```

Note that each image has different dimensions, color depth, format etc so you may get a range of results, I suggest to play with it and create sub keys in the properties that have the most impact for example:

```
{ format : { file_size : quality } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make some kind of simple ML (Machine Learning) approach. Train model that given:

- image size for quality 50
- limit_file_size

as input will produce best quality you seek, or at least narrow down your search so that you need 2-3 iterations instead of 6.

So you would have to gather training (and validation) data, train the model that will be simple and fast (should be fasterer than `save_file`).

I think this is best approach in terms of determining this quality as fast as possible, but requires a lot of work (specially if you have no experience in ML).